# Error: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a drawable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, base-de-datos

me he encontrado con el siguiente error jugando un poco a ver si consigo guardar una fotografía tomada o seleccionada de la galería, en una base de datos, y que aparezca en un RecyclerView cuando añado un elemento.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo, PID: 24393
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo:id/ivperfil with resource ID #0x7f080060
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo:id/ivperfil" (7f080060) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=5 r=0x7f080060}
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:789)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
    at com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo.AdaptadorCustom.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorCustom.kt:45)
    at com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo.AdaptadorCustom.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorCustom.kt:12)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1183)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:889)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:944)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2948)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2635)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Por lo que he podido mirar el error podría estar en las siguientes lineas:
-AdaptadorCustom.kt:45

```
holder.perfil?.setImageResource(item?.perfil!!)
```

-AdaptadorCustom.kt:12

```
class AdaptadorCustom(items: ArrayList<Sondeo>, var listener:ClickListener, var longClickListener: LongClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCustom.ViewHolder>()
```

La verdad es que llevo un buen rato intentando ver cual podría ser el problema y no consigo dar con el.... ¿alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el indicado en el LogCat,

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable
>   com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo:id/ivperfil with resource ID
>   0x7f080060 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.vidamrr.basededatosejemplo:id/ivperfil" (7f080060) **is not a
>   Drawable** (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=5 r=0x7f080060}

aunque indica que el recurso no existe, en realidad la "imagen" que tratas de asignar al `ImageView` `holder.perfil` no es una imagen.

```
holder.perfil?.setImageResource(...)
```

es muy importante asignar un recurso que sea una imagen, por ejemplo:

```
holder.perfil?.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```